# How to integrate GCC Compiler in Java written IDE?

Tags: java, c, gcc, ide

If I am making my own editor written in java then is it possible to run programs written is C Programming Language? if yes then How?

Comment: Yes.  Use `Runtime.exec(...)`.

Comment: Given there are so many free, open source IDEs written in Java which does this already, I would have to ask; Why? and Why not copy what they do?

Comment: @PeterLawrey:Because i am trying to make my own IDE witten in java but for C Language programs. could you please tell me How can i link my editor with GCC compiler?

Comment: You use Runtime.exec, but like I said, instead of re-inventing what has been done many times before, why don't you look at how existing IDEs do it already?  I would look at netbeans first which has the nicest C++ integration IMHO.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: Is there any concept of inserting Subversion svn Repository Of mingw GCC?

Comment: @StephenC:  Is there any concept of inserting Subversion svn Repository Of mingw GCC?

Comment: All the IDEs support subversion and gcc AFAIK, so I would have to say yes.  You should look at how this is done already as well.  There are a few tricks to handling subversion such a merging in your IDE and automatic merges (without you having to worry about them)  For gcc the trick is reading the error messages and displaying them in a friendly manner in your code. e.g. when you have an error you can see a red line under the code which doesn't compile, with the error for that line.

Comment: IN Java you can even get auto-fixes for the errors as you type, though this is harder for C++ as it is a more complex language.

Comment: BTW eclipse and netbeans are over 10 million lines of code so it may take you a while to write something as good as something you can get for free now.

Comment: @PeterLawrey:thanks...this information definitely helps me alot...

Comment: https://netbeans.org/community/sources/ netbeans has about 90 active contributor and eclipse has even more.  It is best to take advantage of that as much as you can.  BTW My preferred IDE is IntelliJ which I believe is the best for Java, but not the best for C/C++ integration.  For example, in netbeans you can debug step from Java code into C++ code when Java calls C++ via JNI.  IntelliJ doesn't do that. AFAIK.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: r u sure that it is possible to link a gcc compiler for C and C++ programs with java written IDE?

Comment: @ParulKalra The IDE is just a program, calling gcc is just another program, the language used doesn't matter.

Comment: @PeterLawrey:okk...thank you so much.....:)

Comment: @PeterLawrey:is GNU Gcc has interpreter? It has compiler and debugger that i know..

Comment: @PeterLawrey:If i want these plugins for my own editor then it is possible to download them or they are integrate with netbeans only?

Comment: Once you understand what they do you can use the plugins however you wish or just copy the code you want, you can get source for the plugins too.

Comment: @PeterLawrey:What is the Purpose of Mingw shell and Msys shell?

Comment: @ParulKalra  You have to consider I have been using shells for almost 30 years so it's not obvious to me what you wouldn't understand about them. Its a prompt for running commands.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: As I want to make an IDE so i have to Link my editor with a Command Prompt like Codeblocks uses mingw Shell, I also want to link my editor with Mingw Shell but how is it possible using java language?

Comment: @ParulKalra You don't need a particular shell to "link" a Java program.  In fact I would use a build system like maven and a IDE like IntelliJ (or netbeans) Using a shell to build your Java program defeats the whole purpose of having an IDE in the first place.  If you think IDEs are a good idea, use an IDE develop your Java program.  If you don't think IDEs are a good idea, why would your write one?

Comment: @PeterLawrey:I don't want to link my java program with shell, actually now i am making an IDE written in Java programming Language but that will be used for Running C Programs.So i have to link that C program written on editor with some shell to see the output so how can I do this kind of Linking?

Comment: A shell is used for interacting with a human.  If you are running a program from another program, you don't need a shell.  What do you need the shell to do that the program you are calling doesn't do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class C_Compile {
public static void main(String args[]){

    String ret = compile();
    System.out.println(ret);

}
    public static String compile()
    {
        String log="";
        String myDirectory = "C:\\";
         try {
             String s= null;
           //change this string to your compilers location,Assume C file is in c:\\Hello.c
             Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /C gcc Hello.c", null, new java.io.File(myDirectory));

         BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new 
              InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
         boolean error=false;

         log+="";
         while ((s = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
             log+=s;
             error=true;
             log+="\n";

         }
         if(error==false) log+="Compilation Successful !!!";

     } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
         return log;
    }


  public int runProgram() 
    {
        int ret = -1;
       try
         {            
             Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
             Process proc = rt.exec("cmd.exe /c start a.exe");
             proc.waitFor();
             ret = proc.exitValue();
         } catch (Throwable t)
           {
             t.printStackTrace();
             return ret;
           }
       return ret;                      
    }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the exec family to run a process. Here is a snippet that yo Use to do this, and read the output of the process, so that I know what it did. You may want this in an IDE to parse error messages from gcc.

```
        Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("mycommand");
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while ((line = input.readLine()) != null)
        {
            // Here you can parse the output of the process.
            System.out.println(line);
        }
```